# Sonar Equals Avoid Null Violation

Tags: java, sonarqube

Fixing sonar violations and got a warning "  Equals Avoid Null:
String literal expressions should be on the left side of an equals comparison." for:

```
if (title != null && !title.equals("")) {
//rest of loop
}
```

I changed it to:

```
if(!("").equals(title) && title != null){
//rest of loop
}
```

Is that change okay? Will it fix the violation? Could somebody possibly explain to me why the original is a violation? I don't understand the issue and have read:
 https://sonar43.spring.io/rules/show/checkstyle:com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.coding.EqualsAvoidNullCheck?layout=false

amongst one or two other articles, but I stil don't see what the problem is...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake I have editted that out. That makes sense, and I'll check for NPE in testing.

Comment: `if (title != null && title.length() > 0)` is better since it doesnt instantiate additional object for empty string.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou or `title != null && !title.isEmpty()`, assuming Java 1.6+. By the way, some static analysis tools like Klocwork warns about comparisons with empty strings as not so efficient...

Comment: @pkalinow `isEmpty()` also works, but if you look at the source code, you see that it is also length check.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou right, it's a syntactic sugar:    
`public boolean isEmpty() {
        return value.length == 0;
}`

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Not entirely disagreeing with your code but the explanation is a bit weird: The `""` literal creates one string object for the whole JVM. I'm sure that's affordable. I'd also recommend `!title.isEmpty()` instead of `title.length() > 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is telling you that it's not sure that `title` won't be `null`. A literal, however, such as your empty string, can never be null by definition. And since `equals` can handle `null` as an argument you're avoiding a potential `NullPointerException` by writing `<literal>.equals(<somebject>)`. If you're not using `title` within the if statement there's no need for further null-checking:

```
if(!"".equals(title)){
    //rest of loop
}
```

However, since you're checking if something *doesn't* equal a literal it makes little sense to let null values pass through.

The [docs](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/coding/EqualsAvoidNullCheck.html) also has this related note:

> Also, it is pretty common to see null check right before equals
>   comparisons which is not necessary [...]

Comment: In this case null checking is actually necessary. The condition `!"".equals(title)` is satisfied by title == null, which is not expected in the if block.

Comment: @pkalinow That's why I said _"If you're not using title within the if statement ..."_ :) In this scenario, when checking if a string is non-empty it seems weird to allow nulls to be considered non-empty though, of course.